# Pages not maintaing state while scrolling

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, flutter-listview, cubit

I created this multiple pages which has different widgets inside it like TextFormField, DropDown, checkBox etc. I created a widget that selects pages on basis of question type fetch from api.
This question selector widget is called inside ListView.builder. I am using cubit to manage state.Each page has it different corresponding cubit.
The problem is each time scroll the widget state is lost.
[image: This is my ui]

My ListView.builder

```
 ListView.builder(
    itemCount: state.question[0].groups![0].items!.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return fetchQuestionWidget(
          question: state.question[0].groups![0].items![index],
           hintText: "",
           imageList: imageList ?? [],
           );
     });
```

My widget selector

```
Widget fetchQuestionWidget(
{JsonItems? question,
String? collectionId,
String? collectionCode,
String? hintText,
String? optionCode,
List<Options>? options,
bool? isParentWidget,
List<File>? imageList,
PageStorageKey? pageStorageKey}) {
    if (question?.type == QuestionTypeConstant.kText) {
       return TextFieldQuestionWidget(
       question: question!,
       hintText: hintText!,
     );
    } else if (question?.type == QuestionTypeConstant.kDate) {
      return DatePickerQuestionWidget(
      question: question!,
     );
    } else if (question?.type == QuestionTypeConstant.kSelection) {
   
   if (question?.renderType == QuestionTypeConstant.kDropdown &&
    !question!.multiple!) {
   return DropDownQuestionWidget(
    question: question,
    options: options,
    key: pageStorageKey,
  );
  } else if ((question?.renderType == QuestionTypeConstant.kDropdown &&
        question!.multiple!) ||
       question?.renderType == QuestionTypeConstant.kTable) {
       return MultiSelectDropDownQuestionWidget(
       question: question!,
    );
  } else if (question?.renderType == QuestionTypeConstant.kSelectionButton &&
    question?.code != 'active') {
        return SelectionButtonQuestionWidget(
        question: question!,
   );
  } else if (question?.renderType == QuestionTypeConstant.kCheckBox) {
  return QtCheckBox(
    question: question!,
    );
  } else {
    return Text('#${question?.type}');
  }
} else if (question?.type == QuestionTypeConstant.kNumber) {
return NumberTextFieldQuestionWidget(
  question: question!,
);
} else if (question?.type == QuestionTypeConstant.kHeading) {
  return HeadingQuestionWidget(question: question!);
} else if (question?.type == QuestionTypeConstant.kPhoto) {
return PhotosQuestionWidget(
     question: question!,
     imageList: imageList,
    );
    } else {
return Text('#${question?.type}');
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not see where you are listening for state changes to question answers, I do not see where you are making state changes to your cubits when those answers are updated. I would need to see more code to say exactly why you are having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to change the state of your cubits is with a method on the cubit, which can then emit the state change. If your state listeners are setup properly, they will update and maintain this newly emitted data. Please check that you are properly updating your cubit state and emitting that state change. Then check that you are properly listening for those state changes and rebuilding your widgets as necessary.